# ではないですか written separately

Tags: grammar, handwriting, sentence

I was reading  a manga when this sentence came up:

暑いではないですか

I first thought it meant "isn't it warm?", however, there was just one thought bubble yet the sentence was written in this format (both vertical rather than horizontal):

first 暑いでは

then ないですか right next to 暑いでは

my question is, why don't write 暑いではないですか all together instead of separately? or is this separation meaningful and it makes the sentence mean something other than "it's not warm"?

Comment: `暑いではないです` is grammatically incorrect.. ("It's not warm/hot" は「暑くないです」「暑くありません」ですよね...) 「暑いではないです**か** 」would make sense, though.. そのページの写真とかアップできます？前後関係と一緒に。。

Comment: You're right, I just missed the か at the end. I will edit now, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a case where a screenshot would definitely help. The user Chocolate is correct that 暑いではないです  as a single thought is grammatically incorrect. So what is going on? Three possibilities occur to me. One, you have incorrectly relayed the information, and it doesn't actually say what you wrote (screenshot would help there). Two, it says exactly what you wrote, and in this one instance the manga author and their editor both let a mistake slip through and get into print. Or three, with the separation that you described, the thought is meant to be taken as 暑いでは...   ないです.  In this case, the では  could have the intended meaning of "じゃ" or "なら" in an "if/then" meaning... Which would translate to something like "Hot?... Ew, gross/No way!" Not being a native speaker, I'm not sure how grammatical that would be, and not seeing the screenshot, I have no idea how fitting to the scene that would be...

Comment: I edited the question, I did miss the か at the end. Is that better? I can't post a pic right now because I'm on a (shitty) phone...

Comment: OK. Well, in answer to your question then, in some speech bubbles, a long sentence just looks awkward in a manga, so that would be the natural place to split that question. I believe it's totally normal and is not meant to change the meaning in any way. And I think as a question it is now a grammatically correct construct, and the meaning would be "Isn't that hot?"